# How successful are modern (2015) sentiment analysis algorithms for identifying emotion?

Tags: emotion, language, language-processing, sentiment-analysis

I see [a number of questions about implementing  text sentiment analysis algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnlp%5D%20sentiment%20analysis) on StackOverflow, and am interested - **how effective are sentiment analysis algorithms at identifying the mood/emotion/affect of the writer?**

In particular, I'm interested in analysis of a diary entries, where an algorithm is required to identify the affect of the writer.